# Convert Long id to Set list using Mapstruct?

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

In a Mapstruct interface, how can I convert an id to a Set< UserSystem > ?

I tried as follows but unsuccessfully because error occurs:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserSystemService.class})
public interface CompanyPostMapper extends EntityMapper<CompanyPostDTO, Company> {

    @Mapping(source = "userSystemId", target = "userSystems", expression = "java(userSystemService.findByIdAndAddToSet(id))")
    Company toEntity(CompanyPostDTO dto);


    default Company fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Company company = new Company();
        company.setId(id);
        return company;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I understood the use of the "uses" parameter correctly, but basically I would like to get the ID and query the register and return a Set with the register.

I was going to try "qualifiedByName" and create a method in the Mapper interface, but I don't know how I can inject the Repository and I don't know if that would be a good practice.

What would be the best way to solve?

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct is a mapping framework. You are doing a lookup inside the mapping. It is possible of course (look at the JPA mapping example where an `@Context` is used). But you can't inherit `EntityMapper<CompanyPostDTO, Company>` at the same time.

Normally, you need to take the lookup outside your mapping logic and use an update method to update the object.

Your mapping would then look like:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring" )
public interface CompanyPostMapper {

   void updateEntity(CompanyPostDTO dto, @MappingTarget Company entity);
}

// and your call would look like:

public class CallingService{
   Company company = userSystemService.findByIdAndAddToSet(id));
   if (company == null) {
     company = new Company();
   }
   companyPostMapper.updateEntity(dto, company);
}
```